# Qt state machine assignProperty does not work

Tags: c++, qt

I tried to get started with a qt statemachine [example-code](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/statemachine-api.html) in qt-creator, but for some reason it does not seem to work. I can build and run the code, but the "label"'s "text"-property does not change/appear, when clicking the "upButton". Has anyone ideas how to debug or get this working?

BTW: I am using qt 4.8, because this is to reuse an older project. But I think that does not matter. I also tried the Qt twowaybutton.pro example without qt-creator generated UI and this works.

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    cout << "hm ..." << endl;
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QStateMachine>
#include <QFinalState>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>
#include <QEventTransition>
#include <QHistoryState>

using namespace std;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->label->setText("initial");
    //ui->label->text() = "initial";

    QStateMachine machine;

    QState *s1 = new QState();
    QState *s2 = new QState();
    QState *s3 = new QState();

    QLabel* object = ui->label;

    s1->assignProperty(object, "text", "state s1");
    s2->assignProperty(ui->label, "text", "state s2");
    s2->assignProperty(ui->label, "text", "state s3");

    s1->addTransition(ui->up_Button, SIGNAL(clicked()), s2);
    s2->addTransition(ui->up_Button, SIGNAL(clicked()), s3);
    s3->addTransition(ui->up_Button, SIGNAL(clicked()), s1);

    machine.addState(s1);
    machine.addState(s2);
    machine.addState(s3);
    machine.setInitialState(s1);

    machine.start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`machine` is local to the constructor, it's deleted just after `machine.start();`
You should declare it as a private member of `MainWindow`